# Internal linking in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

If I have lots of pages... page_ids 1-100... how do I link between the two in the editor?? I guess I can use `<a href="/index.php?page_id=x">Link</a>` but that's not user friendly... I want to do something like `<a href="<?= get_permalink(x); ?>">Link</a>` but that doesn't work either. Is there a handy plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Add the following to your themes’ functions.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists('toscho_id_to_link') )
{
    /**
     * Creates a link from the post id.
     *
     * Usage: [link id=42 title="The Meaning of Life?" class="pseudophilosphical"]Guess![/link]
     *
     * Inspired by Sergej Müller
     * @see    http://playground.ebiene.de/2388/wordpress-shortcode-links/
     * @param  array $atts id (numeric) and additional HTML attributes
     * @param  string $data
     * @return string
     */
    function toscho_id_to_link($atts, $data)
    {
        // incomplete
        if ( ! isset ( $atts['id'] ) or ! is_numeric($atts['id']) )
        {
            return $data;
        }

        // test
        $url = get_permalink($atts['id']);

        // No entry with this ID.
        if ( ! $url )
        {
            return $data;
        }

        unset ( $atts['id'] );

        $attributes = '';

        // more attributes?
        if ( ! empty ($atts) )
        {
            foreach ($atts as $key => $value )
            {
                $attributes .= " $key='$value'";
            }
        }

        return "<a href='$url'$attributes>$data</a>";
    }
    add_shortcode('link', 'toscho_id_to_link');
}
```

You may find this plugin helpful: [Simply show IDs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simply-show-ids/).

Answer (score 1):

We use [RB-Internal-Links](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rb-internal-links/other_notes/). It allows you to link using a shortcode and slug, or even has a WYSIWYG interface.

Comment: I was about to suggest that plugin, as I use it myself, but looks like I found this question a few days too late.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins that you can use to insert PHP in your posts or pages.  Maybe using one of those will let you use your second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use complete and full URLs for all links in WordPress. http://example.com/index.php?page_id=123 , for example.

Using partial links will result in strange behaviors in feeds, on category archives, etc.